# Trying and expand the contrib.auth.user model and add a "relationships" manage

Tags: python, django, model, authentication

I have the following model setup.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SomeManager(models.Manager):
    def friends(self):
        # return friends bla bla bla


class Relationship(models.Model):
    """(Relationship description)"""
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user')
    has_requested_friendship = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_friend = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = SomeManager()

relationships = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=Relationship, symmetrical=False)
relationships.contribute_to_class(User, 'relationships')
```

Here i take the User object and use contribute_to_class to add 'relationships' to the User object. The relationship show up, but if call User.relationships.friends it should run the friends() method, but its failing. Any ideas how i would do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using the user profile feature?  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users  This should be the proper way to add features to the `User` class.

Comment: I'm hoping to release this as an 'app' and not every user has the profile module setup.

Comment: It's a one-line change to `settings`, so everyone *could* have the profile module configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this instead.

```
f= Relationships.objects.filter( from_user=some_user, is_friend=True )
```

That saves trying to mess around with User.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing the ".objects" in the call:

```
User.relationships.objects.friends()
```

Comment: Throws the error 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'objects'

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Django to use your manager for related lookups - by default, it uses a standard one for those. You need to set `use_for_related_fields` on the Manager - see [the documentation on this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types).